# Iterate over a vector of a list of pairs

Tags: c++, list, vector, iterator, std-pair

I'm trying to iterate over a vector of a list of pairs and I keep getting compilation errors. I am trying to find a match for the first element of the pair.

Here is the code on cpp shell: http://cpp.sh/4ir4p

and this is the code:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector < list < pair <string, string> > > v;
    v.resize(15);
    string k = "foo";

    //want to try and find match
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        if(v[i].first == k)
            cout << "true";

    for (const auto & itr : v)
        if(itr.first == k)
            cout << "true";

    cout << "YAY";
}
```

and I keep getting error for both methods saying I have no member named first, I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, thanks for anyhelp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you are getting compiler errors, `std::vector` has no member called `first`. When you iterate through the vector your iterator points to a list of pairs, you want to compare. So you need a second loop:

```
int main()
{
   vector < list < pair <string, string> > > v;
   v.resize(15);
   string k = "foo";

   for (const auto &itList : v)
   {
      for (const auto &itPair : itList)
      {
         if (itPair.first == k)
         {
            cout << "true";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: this will probably just promote my misunderstanding of the logic but why would `itList.erase(itPair);` in place of `cout << "true";` cause errors? aren't I just erasing that pair from the list?

Comment: @user3470987: Erasing an element in an vector, list, etc. you are just iterating trough leads to undefined behaviour. So please do never erase or add new elements to the data structure during the iteration. If your goal is to find element you want to erase, then introduce another list or vector called EraseList. After you finished the iterating process you can run another loop that makes the deletion.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, wouldnt I just be iterating over eraselist trying to find the element and then deleting it, duplicating the above process?

Comment: @user3470987: That is correct, in the second loop you will iterate over eraselist and for every entry of eraselist a call to v hast to be made, to erase that entry. It would only duplicate the process if you are going to erase whole v. I'm guessing that the entries you want to be removed are arbitariliy in v and not linear, so there is no elegant way that is safe to find and remove the entries. At least it is not with this basic data structures.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96383/discussion-between-user3470987-and-viktor-liehr).

Answer (score 1):

you must introduce a second loop for the list like:

```
//want to try and find match
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        for (auto itr=v[i].begin(); itr != v[i].end(); itr++)
            if(itr->first == k)
            cout << "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
vector < list < pair <string, string> > > v;
```

you define a `vector<list<pair>>`, so later `v[i]` is a `list`, not a pair. Don't you just need a `vector<pair>` instead?

Comment: this is part of a larger project dealing with hashtables so I wasnt sure how to incorporate that in a little snippet of code

Comment: @user3470987 Well then you need to iterate over `vector[i]`, which is a `list`.